# User-friendly way to end a loop in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm still working on this VBScript script that types things for you for a video game I play. The reason why I'm still working on it is because I can't find a user-friendly way to stop the loop on the very bottom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type `Do While`). Every single thing works except for this stupid loop.

I've tried making a batch script that is just `pause` and to check for `cmd.exe`'s process, but that didn't work for some reason. If you could figure it out, I'd prefer for that to be the way to end the loop. However, I don't really care which way you do it, as long as it's somewhat user-friendly (manually ending the `wscript.exe` process in Task Manager would obviously not be user-friendly).

```
Set objC = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Sub sleep(Timesec)
  objC.Run "Timeout /T " & Timesec & " /nobreak", 0, True
End Sub

sleep(1)
objA = False
objH = False

objF = MsgBox("The Sell All Script that is a meme. By Vncz. Start?", 68, "Hello!")

Function chatsMessageBox()
  Do
    MsgBox "No."
  Loop
End Function

If objF = vbYes Then
  objB = InputBox("What is the username for your alt to pay? ALL LOWERCASE PLEASE, and '+(-)' for underscores.", "Username to pay")
Else
End If

If objB = "" Then
  objH = True
Else
  xdddddddddddddd = MsgBox("Press OK to check the username.", 64, "Check Username")
End If

If objF = vbNo Then
  objH = True
  MsgBox "Canceled."
Else
End If

If objH = True Then
  objA = False
ElseIf objB = "chatshitgetsplit" Then
  objD = MsgBox("No.", "16", "No.")
Else
  objE = MsgBox("Press OK to start the loop; run stop.bat to stop the loop.", 64, "You're in!")
End If

If objD = vbOK Then
  chatsMessageBox()
Else
End If

If objE = vbOK Then
  objA = True
Else
End If

'[]
'In place of this comment, stop the loop somehow (If something, objA = False)
'[]

Do While objA = True
  sleep(5)
  objC.SendKeys "t"
  sleep(1)
  objC.SendKeys "/sell all"
  sleep(1)
  objC.SendKeys "~"
  sleep(5)
  objC.SendKeys "t"
  sleep(1)
  objC.SendKeys "/pay " & objB & " 10000"
  sleep(1)
  objC.SendKeys "~" 
Loop
```

Comment: I hope to $deity that the chatsMessageBox function is never called...

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Do While loop, place code like the following:

```
If <your condition> Then Exit Do
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is definitely editing that loop to end by default after a certain condition is met.  At a quick glance, I see no exit for that loop no matter what the case.  It will just continue sleeping and sending keys.  Is that truly what you wanted?

1) Are you just supposed to iterate through that loop once? If that's the case, no reason for a loop.

2) If you know the number of times you want to iterate through those steps, you can use a counter. Example:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 0

Do Until i = 5
    'rest of code'

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

This will allow you to loop through a set number of times.

By having it loop while `objA = True` and never looking at `objA` or calling another function/sub during your loop, it won't chnage.

3) If you are just trying to exit your loop once something is done and you know what that is, you can also do an `if` statement inside of the loop.

```
Do While objA = True
    'rest of code'
    If <condition> = True Then Exit Do
Loop
```